Adobe Commerce Cloud: Can we set the build, deploy and post-deploy variable through cloud console?
I am studying the adobe commerce cloud, and my question about the Variables used in the .magento.env.yaml file. Can we set the variable from global, build, deploy and post-deploy through project web interface or cloud console. For example QUEUE_CONFIGURATION, CACHE_CONFIGURATION or any other variables from the below links
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/env/stage/variables-global
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/env/stage/variables-build
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/env/stage/variables-deploy
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/env/stage/variables-post-deploy
I want to understand that the variables that are we set in .magento.env.yaml file for build, deploy and post-deploy stage could we set them through cloud console or it is only can set in the .magento.env.yaml file?
